# How to `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` in a series of orderby parameters

Tags: wp-query, sort, meta-value

I'm running a site for a book store. Each book has a catalogue number. These numbers are often a string with numbers in it. For example- `PUB 1` would be a common entry, as well as `PUB 12`. Right now, it's sorting `PUB 10` after `PUB 1` but before `PUB 2`. What do I need to do to have its sort order go: `PUB 1, PUB 2... PUB 9, PUB 10`?

Here's my current code.

```php
<?php
$labelargs= array(
    'post_type'      => 'book',
    'posts_per_page' => 1000000,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation'  => 'OR',
            'otherinfo' => array(
                'key'     => 'wpcf-other-information',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
            'otherinfonotexists' => array(
                'key'     => 'wpcf-other-information',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
        'wpcf_catalogue_number' => array(
            'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',                //I don't think this is the right place for this
            'key'            => 'wpcf-catalogue-number',
        ),
        'parent_release_year' => array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-parent-release-year',
        ),
        'release_year' => array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-release-year',
        ),
        'format' => array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-format',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'        => array(
        //I tried 'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', here but it didn't work
        'wpcf_catalogue_number' => 'ASC',
        'format'                => 'ASC',
        'parent_release_year'   => 'ASC',
        'release_year'          => 'ASC',
        'otherinfo'             => 'ASC',
        
    ),
);


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) indicates that ordering by meta value is limited to one meta key and requires the `meta_key` parameter (untested):

```php
$results = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_key' => 'wpcf_catalogue_number',
    'orderby'  => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
    ),
) );
```

If you want additional sorting, you'll need to sort the result (`$results->posts`) using PHP (untested):

```php
$sort__formats = array();
// Other sorting arrays.

foreach ( $results->posts as $post ) {
    $formats[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'format', true );
    // Other values added to sorting arrays.
}

array_multisort( $results->posts, $sort__formats, SORT_ASC, ... );
```

This won't be highly performant, so you'll likely want to consider a more performant approach, like combining all the meta values into one, and sorting off of that.

Comment: Thanks Caleb. Can you share a bit more about what function I would use to sort that? How can I find more information about that type of code?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I updated my code to use `$query = new WP_Query($labelargs);

    foreach ( $query->posts as $post ) {
     $catnumbers[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpcf-catalogue-number', true );
     // Other values added to sorting arrays.
    }
    array_multisort($catnumbers, SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL) ;
    
    print_r($catnumbers);`. the print_r is in the right order, but the results of my query are not. How do I resolve that?

Comment: Add `$query->posts` as first parameter of `array_multisort()`. See code in answer.

Comment: got it! needed to do it like this: `array_multisort($catnumbers, SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL, $query->posts) ;`. Thanks so much!